# mySQL event alternative

Tags: mysql, events, phpmyadmin

I am using a host gator shared hosting plan, and need to execute a simple command every minute:

```
UPDATE table_info SET expired = 1 WHERE TIMESTAMP(dateTime) <= NOW()
```

My problem is that I cant turn on the event scheduler because I don't have permissions for it. Can anyone think of a simple way to do this without using events?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your update statement into simple PHP script, and run it via cron.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to get it set up.

Answer (score 0):

Using cron or any other OS based task scheduler is stricktly speaking an answer to this question.

However, it is not really a best practice to run any event every minute. Particularly not, if the operation done could be executed on the fly, like here. The expired flag's value depends on a simple calculation:

```
dateTime <= NOW()
```

Instead of running this calculation every minute on the entire `table_info`, you could

1. place the sql command into a regularly executed script
2. just embedd the logic into any reporting or other operation which depend on the expired field and get rid of the flag completely.